# ClickOnce: how vb.NET application get HTTPResponse headers when start

Tags: .net, vb.net, clickonce

Is it possible to get the launch http context with the `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment` libraries? I would like to get the `httpresponse` headers that started the application.

My .application is called from an http: or https://server/myapp.application?parameters URL and runs a myapp.exe written in vb.NET. From vb.NET I would like to be able to analyze the response headers that triggered the call of `myapp.application`.

Thank you.

I'm found this sample code but `HttpWebResponse` method is not found!

```
If (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    ApplicationDeployment deployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
    String[] headers = **deployment.UpdateLocation.HttpWebResponse.Headers.AllKeys**;
    foreach(String header In headers)
    {
        String value = deployment.UpdateLocation.HttpWebResponse.Headers[header];
        Console.WriteLine($"{header}: {value}");
    }
}
```